# How to add a new property to an existing json without defining model class in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

```
{
    "version": "15.1",
    "count": 8,
    "data": [
        {
            "furit_items": [
                {
                    "price": 12.6,
                    "base_price": 6.59,
                    "text": "banana",
                    "product_id": "1234",
                    "product_name": "banana",
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ],
            "product_sub_total": 12.6,
            "product_total": 12.6,
            "shipments": []
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my json data getting through a service.

Is this possible to add a new property {"quality":"good"} under "furit_items" object?

Comment: What is class of this object?

Comment: Don't have class . I am getting this json through service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
dynamic original = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(object));
original.data[0].furit_items[0].quality = good;
var modifiedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(original , Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: I have tried this, and it works for me. (Put quotes on the good, "good")

Comment: Error : Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: original.data[0].furit_items[0].quality = "good"; - this what I have checked

Comment: The name of the your JSON has to be replaced with json in the first line of the answer. Did you do that?

Comment: dynamic original = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result, typeof(object));
 original.data[0].furit_items[0].quality = "good";
 var modifiedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(original, Formatting.Indented);

Comment: Then lets see how you getting the result from the service?

Comment: Hey its working... Actually it was my mistake... Your solution is working great... Thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

why you do not want to define the model class ? i totally recommend it, since whatever you do become more safe and easy. http://json2csharp.com/ simply generate the model for you.

if you do not want to use the model at least use json.net - jobject.

Comment: couldn't define modal class because it is a dynamic json data

Comment: so how can you find the path of adding a new property ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Linq to Json of Json.Net as

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsontext);
obj["new_prop"] = "value";//new property as per hirarchy ,same for replacing values
string newjson=obj.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try like this,it is  easy for using javascript code.

> **data.furit_items.field={"quality":"good"}**